# Add to cart button on category view template

Tags: magento-1.7, addtocart, bundled-product

i'm working on an heavy customised magento site and there is a `catalog/product/view/list.phtml` which shows 2 product categories on the same page. The combination of the 2 products should create a bundle product but adding it to the cart doesn't work as it options are not stored properly in the database.
I believe I need to add those 2 blocks

```
bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle.phtml
```

and

```
bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/options.phtml
```

to generate the Json array with all options. I'm not able to load them because I'm working on the `category_view` block, while I need the `product_view` block so `$this->getJsonConfig()`  will work.
Tried to include

```
<block type="bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle" name="product.info.bundle" as="product_type_data" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle.phtml">
```

but as soon as I insert it I got a fatal error.

Can anyone help, please?
thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is for sure caused by the fact that you have no product in the registry. The `Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle` block extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Abstract` which loads the product from the registry. The value in the registry on the other hand is set in the product controller, view action. Therefor loading that block on the category page will never work.

However, you can override the category block and add the missing method inside, and adapt it.
Write your own module, extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` and add 2 methods: `getJsonConfig` and `getOptions` (both from the bundle view). The only difference is that you will need to pass the product as an argument, and don't load it using the `$this->getProduct()` method. Something like this:

```
foreach($productCollection as $product):
    $jsonConfig = $this->getJsonConfig($product);
endforeach;
```

I can't guarantee that this is the best solution to achieve your goal, but it's a starting point. The downside is that these methods seem to a lot of loads from the database, therefor it will slow the page.

Comment: thank you, will give a shot, it should not slow down the page as in that particular category view i will select only 1 bundle product.